# Issue with integrating facebook into kivy with buildozer

Tags: android, python, facebook, kivy, buildozer

I'm attempting to integrate Facebook login into my kivy app but whenever I try to run the app it crashes as the SDK hasn't been added by buildozer.

Anyone have any pointers on how to correctly configure a buildozer spec file to include the facebook SDK correctly? I've included the ways I've attempted this below i.e. via the java files directly or the library reference.

## (list) List of Java files to add to the android project

android.add_src = facebook-android-sdk-3.23.1/facebook/src/com/facebook/android

## (list) Android library project to add

android.library_references = facebook-android-sdk-3.23.1/facebook, google-play-services_lib

Been trying to solve this for a while, hope someone can assist.

Comment: maybe this [link](https://blog.kivy.org/2013/08/using-facebook-sdk-with-python-for-android-kivy/) might help you.

Comment: That sadly does not work for me, I've tried it in the past @phunsukwangdu